# Initialize a three dimensional matrix in Rust using the "nalgebra" crate

Tags: rust, nalgebra

How can I initialize a 3D matrix in Rust given the number number of component in x, y, z and a given number for initialization (let's say `1.0`). At the moment I use no libraries:

```
let ny: usize = 400;  // x-resolution
let nx: usize = 100;  // y-resolution
let nl: usize = 4000; // z-resolution

let f = vec![vec![vec![1.0; nl]; ny]; nx];
```

But I think there should be a more efficient way in the nalgebra library, but everything seems really cumbersome.

Comment: see [nalgebra](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#examples-1) examples

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is not nalgebra, but [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/).

The former is a crate for linear algebra, which focuses on vectors and 2D matrices, and the latter handles multi-dimensional data.

The [crate's docs](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#array) have examples on how to achieve what you want:

```rust
use ndarray::Array3;
let f = Array3::<f64>::ones((nx, ny, nl));
```